# ¿Cómo hago que un input acepte solamente un formato (+595)?

Tags: php, javascript, html

tengo un form en html, en la cual como uno de los campos es un teléfono, pero solo quiero aceptar el formato +595981123456,

intente hacerlo con el atributo "pattern", pero sigue sin validar,

```
<div class="col-4">
  <div class="form-label">Teléfono Particular</div>
   <div class="input-group col-12">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tel_tt" id="tel_tt" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Ingrese el número en formato internacional (+595)" placeholder="+595981123456" required="" pattern="[09]|[+595]" >
   </div>                                                
</div>
```

Alguna sugerencia para solucionarlo,

Desde ya, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ha Upei? Tenes dos opciones:
La primera y la mas simple seria con el [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel) html de la siguiente forma
`pattern="[+]{1}[595]{3}[0-9]{9}"`

La otra opción seria con Javascript, podes descomentar el código en Javascript para poder probarlo. Utilizando [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) y [eventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) es una forma de solucionar tu problema.

Espero que el código de ejemplo te sirva de guia. Saludos!

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('enviar')

function validarTelefono() {
  let telefonoEl = document.getElementById('tel_tt').value
  let formatoInt = telefonoEl.slice(0,4)
  if (formatoInt === '+595'){
    return true
  }
  return false
}

function checkTelefono(){
  if (validarTelefono()) {
    alert('Telefono ok!')
  } else {
    alert('Problema con formato internacional')
    let telefonoEl = document.getElementById('tel_tt')
    telefonoEl.focus()
  }
}

//btn.addEventListener('click', checkTelefono)
```

```html
<form>
<div class="col-4">
  <div class="form-label">Teléfono Particular</div>
   <div class="input-group col-12">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tel_tt" id="tel_tt" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Ingrese el número en formato internacional (+595)981123456" placeholder="+595981123456" pattern="[+]{1}[595]{3}[0-9]{9}" required>
   </div>                                                
</div>
<button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar un plugin de jQuery como https://css-tricks.com/input-masking/

Prueba por ejemplo:

```
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="form-label">Teléfono Particular</div>
       <div class="input-group col-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tel_tt" id="tel_tt" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Ingrese el número en formato internacional (+595)" placeholder="+595981123456" required="" pattern="[09]|[+595]" >
       </div>                                                
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
$("#tel_tt").inputmask({"mask": "(+999) 999-9999"});
    </script>
```

Comment: Hola! Recuerda hacer que tus respuestas sean algo más que un enlace. Alguna pista sobre cómo usar lo que está en el enlace, algún ejemplo, etc. Si el enlace se rompe, el sitio desaparece, cambian el SEO, tu respuesta deja de servirle a los que lleguen después con la misma pregunta.

Comment: Ok, gracias por los comentarios, voy a mejorar mi respuesta :)